# Keep both non-overlapping intervals and overlapping ones with a larger id MySQL

Tags: mysql, query, time, interval

I have the following table in MySQL: `data(interval_id, object_id, start, end)`, where `interval_id, object_id` are integers and `interval_id` is unique per every `object_id`, while `object_id` itself is unique. `start`, `end` are timestamps(and `end` can be `NULL`).

Say that I want to eliminate overlapping intervals but if there's any, I want to keep the ones with the highest `interval_id`.

For the interval elimination, I am using the following criteria:

```
(t1.start <=t2.end or t2.end IS NULL) AND (t1.end>=t2.start OR t1.end IS NULL)
```

I am doing a (self) CROSS JOIN and have something like this already:

```
SELECT t1.object_id, t1.interval_id, t1.start, t1.stop
FROM data AS t1, data AS t2
WHERE t1.object_id = t2.object_id -- we want to compare same objects
AND (t1.start <=t2.end or t2.end IS NULL) AND (t1.end>=t2.start OR t1.end IS NULL)) --overlapping condition
AND t1.interval_id > t2.interval_id --keep ones with the highest id?
```

My main question is if this is a correct approach to keep both non-overlapping intervals and overlapping intervals with the highest `interval_id` or am I doing anything wrong? I wish I could fully test out myself but I currently don't have access to the db, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: *I have the following table in MySQL* Provide the table as complete CREATE TABLE, not as verbal description. *eliminate overlapping intervals* Does adjacency is treated as overlapping?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3